# Cmake, как собрать готовую библиотеку со статической линковкой (т.е. статически слинковать все внешние зависимости этой библиотеки сразу в неё)?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, google-protobuf

Есть проект, куда все внешние либы линкуются статически (на таргет машинах нет возможности распространять новые версии этих либ). Сейчас необходимо обновить google protobuf. В новой версии этой библиотеки они полностью перешли на cmake и добавили новые внешние зависимости, такие как absl. После сборки и установки google protobuf на build машине проект со статической линковкой не собирается т.к. линковщик не может найти функции библиотеки absl внутри a'шников протобафа.
Как мне в процессе сборки protobuf, заставить cmake линковать все зависимости в a'шники протобафа статически?

```
cmake -Dprotobuf_BUILD_TESTS=OFF .
cmake --build . -j12 --clean-first
sudo cmake --install .
```

Такими командами собираю протобаф. Какой флаг мне нужно добавить, чтобы линковщик собрал всё статически т.е. не оставлял в `а` файлах протобафа никаких внешних ссылок?

- Система сборки проекта тоже cmake.
- Build машина: Ubuntu 22.04
- Target машина: Debian.
- Cmake 3.22
- GCC-12

P.S.
После установки протобафа в систему сами a'шники absl лежат в каталоге протобафа. Возможно имеет смысл подхватить их. Но у меня так и не получилось сделать это из cmake скрипта моего проекта.

Comment: XY problem. Как **вы** прицепляетесь к протобуфу? При правильном прицеплении CMake должен подтянуть и все зависимости самого протобуфа.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите документацию/CMakeLists.txt файл собираемой библиотеки. Обычно в CMake, если опустить тип сборки (`add_library(my_lib)` vs `add_library(my_lib SHARED)`), таргет будет собираться статически, а с помощью флага `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` можно вызвать динамическую сборку, ничего не меняя в CMakeLists.txt. Так что если с вашими командами такого не происходит, то смотрите документацию, как сделано в искомой библиотеке, — может там наоборот есть флаг типа `protobuf_BUILD_STATIC` либо статическая сборка вообще не поддерживается.